# Putting the lines of a txt file in a revered order in linux

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

Is there a way to show data in a file in reverse order ?
input file is:

```
string1
string2
string3
```

i would like it to be

```
string3
string2
string1
```

*don't want the data to be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what `tac` does.

> tac - concatenate and print files in reverse

Just do

```
tac file
```

Comment: just found this as well ```sed '1!G;h;$!d' ${inputfile}```

Comment: @Ziv Yes, I guess that's a more portable option. While sed is a standard utility, tac only comes with GNU coreutils